# Error while running docker compose up while connecting to sql database

Tags: mysql, database, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have setup docker environment in my local machine to run our development code by pointing to dev mysql database url. Done all configurations and was able to build the docker using **`docker-compose build`** command. Even though i was able to build it successfully ,  on running the command **`docker-compose up`** , i am getting numerous errors.

Few of the errors are :

> ERROR - TransactionManager Failed to start new registry transaction.
>
> ERROR- AsyncIndexer. Error while indexing

[image: TransactionManager Failed to start new registry transaction]

I saw another answers in stackoverflow and updated my code accordingly like limiting max active connections to  field to 50 in *master-datasources.xml* file and changing the configuration url to the below format.

> jdbc:mysql://${db_url}:${db_port}/${carbon_db}?autoReconnect=true&relaxAutoCommit=true

**Docker version** : 19.03.5

**Docker compose version** : 1.24.1

My **docker-compose.yml** file:

```
services:
  wso2am:
    build: ./apim
    image: wso2am:2.1.0
    env_file:
      - sample.env
    ports:
      - "9444:9444"
      - "8281:8281"
      - "8244:8244"
    depends_on:
      - wso2is-km
  wso2is-km:
    build: ./is-as-km
    image: wso2is-km:5.3.0
    env_file:
      - sample.env
    ports:
      - "9443:9443"
```

My **sample.env** file:

```
HOST_NAME=<hostname>
DB_URL=<db_connection_url>
DB_USER=admin
DB_PASS=adminpassword
DB_PORT=3306
CARBON_DB=carbondb
APIM_DB=apimdb
ADMIN_PASS=<wso2_password>
```

Can anyone provide a solution for this issue.

Comment: What's the image you've included in the question?  You say it produces errors; can you include those, as text, in your question, along with enough code or configuration to produce a [mcve]?

Comment: @DavidMaze : I have added the my env file and docker-compose.yml file for referencealong with the errors am facing. Hope you can give suggestions using the data i have provided .